# Can not connect socket.io to express4

Tags: express, socket.io

My `app.js` file looks like

```
let express = require('express');
let path = require('path');
let favicon = require('serve-favicon');
let logger = require('morgan');
let cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let dotEnv = require('dotenv');
let helmet = require('helmet');
let compression = require('compression');
let passport = require('passport');

let socket_io = require("socket.io");
let app = express();

let io = socket_io();
app.io = io;
require('./server/config/socket')(io);

let useragent = require('express-useragent');
let cors = require('cors');
dotEnv.load();

require('./server/authentication/passport.local');


app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'server/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(cors());
//app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(helmet());
app.use(useragent.express());
app.use(compression())
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

/** 
 * Custom middle ware functions 
 */


require('./server/middleware/authentication-middleware')(app);
require('./server/config/database')(app, process.env.NODE_ENV);
require('./server/routes')(app);
require('./server/middleware/custom-middleware')(app);
module.exports = app;
```

`www` file

```
let server = http.createServer(app);
let io = app.io;
io.attach(server);
```

`socket.is` file

```
module.exports = function(io) {
  io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('Socket.io is connected');
  });
}
```

I have tried so many ways, but it does not fire the connection message. Does anyone here help me what is going wrong?

`package.json` file

expressjs : **4.16.0**

socket.io : **2.0.4**

Meanwhile, I have tried some other instruction, but does not work: `https://onedesigncompany.com/news/express-generator-and-socket-io`

Thanks in advance

Comment: is there anyone around can help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In client side you can use socket.io-client

```
let socket = ClientSocket({ transports: ['websocket'] });
socket.on('connection',()=>{
    console.log("")
})
```

And then at server(Considering that you have server instance.)

```
var socketIo = require("socket.io");
var io = socketIo.listen(server.listener);
io.on('connection', function (socketInstance) {
      console.log("connected to server");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to pass `io` to your routes to make it available:

```
require('./server/routes')(app, io);
```

Or use with Express Router:

```
const yourSpecificRoute = require('./server/youRoutes)(io);
const router = express.Router();

router.use('/route', yourSpecificRoute);
```

Comment: So, how to use io in routes ?